# Why do you need to close the paragraphs,links,images etc in html?

Tags: html

im just starting to learn html and i was wondering why you need to close out the < p > with a < /p > or others like < a > with < /a > etc. If you dont close it out and just leave it as < p > and then go directly to the next part of the website wont it look the same?

Comment: HTML is based on SGML which is like XML. I suggest you to learn **Jade** if you want to code HTML that is without closing tags - http://jade-lang.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser parsing the code needs to know where the element ends since tags can potentially be nested within one another.

For example, If I were to have `<p>Here is some text<a>and a link<p> and more text.` by your semantics, it would be impossible to tell if the link is supposed to be within the paragraph text or after the paragraph text.

It could translate as:

```
<p>here is some text<a>and a link</a></p>
<p>and more text</p>
```

or

```
<p>here is some text</p>
<a>and a link</a>
<p>and more text</p>
```

or possibly even

```
<p>here is some text<a>and a link<p>and more text</p></a></p>
```

which would make the entire second paragraph clickable as a link.

The reason that it "looks the same" when you load it into a browser is that many browsers will try their best to correct bad html so that the user still sees *something* (as opposed to the site crashing or not displaying at all or displaying an error)

Comment: @JackV: if that answered your question, please mark answer as accepted (checkmark to the left)

Answer (score 0):

Leaving Out Closing Tags is Not All Good. There are some important reasons not to leave the closing tags:

**The closing tags provide structure:**

> When you have an HTML document that is minimally coded it might load quickly, but it could rapidly become a bear to maintain. Adding new table rows or columns can be a lot harder to do quickly without the full structure of the beginning and end tags. And often people solve this by indenting which adds the characters back into the document, thus negating the speed benefits you gained from leaving them out.

**CSS and JavaScript hook on the full elements:**

> While most browsers can display (and style) tags without their closing tags, the lack of closing tags can make a definitive location for closing a style or script action less clear. If you are working with very precise layouts, you give up control over the precision when you leave out closing tags—you are letting the browser decide where the tag ends. Sometimes browsers guess right, and sometimes not.

**Omitting closing tags is not always allowed:**

> In HTML5, the `</p>` tag may be omitted when the paragraph is immediately followed by around 25 different elements. But there are over 100 elements in HTML5. Are you going to memorize every situation that it's valid to leave off the end tag? It's probably easier to just include it.

**XHTML Requires All Closing Tags:**

> The main reason most people use closing tags with these elements is because of XHTML. When you write XHTML the closing tags are always required. If you plan on converting your web documents to XHTML at any point in the future, it's easiest to include the closing tags, so that your documents are ready.

[Click here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/optional-html-end-tags-when-to-include-them.htm) for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

Without closing the tag, all of your content is inside one tag. This makes it impossible to control your content when you get into more advanced HTML.

For example, if I wanted the first div to be blue and the second div to be black, using this:
`<div style='color:blue;'>Blue section.<div>Black (normal) section.`
would result in all of the divs being blue.

By closing the end tag, you will get your desired result.
`<div style='color:blue;'>Blue section.</div><div>Black (normal) section.</div>`

You can play with a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ea8zpcuu/

I hope this helps!
Good luck with HTML!